# Django Timezone is not displayed correctly

Tags: python, django, datetime, pytz, django-timezone

In my Django application I set `USE_TZ = True` and `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'`.

My dates and time are displayed like:

```
Sept. 27, 2014, 3 pm.
```

In my opinion, and according to the specified timezone, the date and time should be displayed something like this:

```
27. Sept 2014, 15:00
```

I tried the following:

```
print(request.session.get('django_timezone'))
--> None
print(timezone.get_current_timezone_name())
--> Europe/Berlin
```

This gives me the conclusion, that the timezone is not recognized.

But why is that?
I am using a Gentoo Linux with `pytz` installed.

```
$ date
Mi 24. Sep 10:43:54 CEST 2014
```

As you can see the timezone is set accordingly on my system.